# Drop Down freezing when selecting a value from uiwebview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, uiwebview

i am having a UIWebview having some dropdowns on selecting a dropdown value. I am calling a javascript alert 
which freezes the app in iPad . clicking on device home button & opening the app un-freezes the app

```
<cfcontent reset="true" /><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=3">
<title>freeze!</title>
</head>
<body>
</div>
<div style="height: 100px;">
    &lt;select> with onchange event
    <select id="select" onchange= "actualFunction()">
        <option value="ONE">one</option>
        <option value="TWO">two</option>
        <option value="THREE">three</option>
    </select>
app freezes on selection because of javascript blocking onchange 
event
</div>  <!--- <div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div style="width: 25%; float: left;">
    <select id="three">
        <option value="ONE">one</option>
        <option value="TWO">two</option>
        <option value="THREE">three</option>
    </select>
</div> --->
```

```
js function
function actualFunction()
{
    if(document.getElementById('select').value !="d")
    {
        alert('yes');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: The issue appears to be the alert() in the event handler.  If you remove the alert() and replace with some other function it works fine.

Comment: @DustinSimpson I am calling the js function after a delay of 5sec. then it works fine

the root cause of the issue -
on clicking a drop down values, the view will animate while it disappears I am calling the alert at the same time so it freezes the app 

wait for few sec to close the animation then call the alert works for me